# Error installing laravel using composer

Tags: php, laravel-5

when I enter the "composer global require "laravel/installer" " this ouput will be show.

> chmod() : no such directory file

[image: screenshot]

Comment: run  "composer self-update" first

Comment: not work.., same error still happen

Comment: can you confirm that you can go to "C:/Users/amhad/AppData/Roaming/Composer" in explorer?

Comment: try manually creating the folder in the given path

Answer (score 0):

### Step 1

Install Composer manually download link **https://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe**

after successfully install go through next step.

### Step 2

1. open command window
2. make sure composer is install. For this instance type this command on command window: C:\Users\amhad>**composer**
3. if composer install it's show all composer command and big composer graphics

### laravel install command

```
C:\Users\amhad>composer create-project laravel/laravel blog --prefer-dist
```

Note: The **blog** is your director name where laravel all files are copied.

Answer (score 0):

But note, if you install composer, you need to include it in your list of environment variables before you can access it on the command line.

[Here](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml) is how to create an environment variable on windows